# How to perform Kernel Density Estimation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, kernel-density

I'm trying to write a Kernel Density Estimation algorithm in Tensorflow.

When fitting the KDE model, I am iterating through all the data in the current batch and, for each, I am creating a kernel using the `tensorflow.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag` object:

`self.kernels = [MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=data, scale=bandwidth) for data in X]`

Later, when trying to predict the likelihood of a data point with respect to the model fitted above, for each data point I am evaluating, I am summing together the probability given by each of the kernels above:

`tf.reduce_sum([kernel._prob(X) for kernel in self.kernels], axis=0)`

This approach only works when `X` is a numpy array, as TF doesn't let you iterate over a Tensor. My question is whether or not there is a way to make the algorithm above work with `X` as a `tf.Tensor` or `tf.Variable`?

Answer (score 0):

One answer that I found for this problem tackles the problem of fitting the KDE and predicting the probabilities in one fell swoop. The implementation is a bit hacky, though.

```
def fit_predict(self, data):
    return tf.map_fn(lambda x: \ 
        tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(
            tf.map_fn(lambda x_i: self.kernel_dist(x_i, self.bandwidth).prob(x), self.fit_X)),
            tf.multiply(tf.cast(data.shape[0], dtype=tf.float64), self.bandwidth[0])), self.X)
```

The first `tf.map_fn` iterates through the data for which we are calculating the likelihood, summing together the probabilities from each of the individual kernels.

The second `tf.map_fn` iterates through all the data that we use to fit our model, and creates a `tf.contrib.distributions.Distribution` (here this is parameterized by `kernel_dist`).

`self.X` and `self.fit_X` are placeholders that are created when initializing the `KernelDensity` object.